# save data when back button is tapped

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have a simple navigation based app which has a bunch fo forms in it, I have a method connected to a button that saves data when the button is tapped but I was wondering if I could call the same method when the back button is tapped in the navigation? Just incase a user fails to use the save button. If it is possible, how would I go about it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view controller's `viewWillDisappear:` method will be invoked when the back button is pressed (but also at other times), so that might be an option.

However, `viewWillDisappear:` will also be invoked if you present (say) a modalViewController, or push another viewController onto the navigation stack.

The only method I can think of that will be invoked *only* when the controller is popped from the navigation stack is the `-dealloc` method.

Comment: viewWillDisappear sounds like the way to go, there aren't going to be any views being pushed onto the stack once the users reach the edit pages, thanks a lot for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, in the `viewWillDisappear:` method of the UIViewController.